# Fatal Error Error in in magento using PayuBiz extension

Tags: magento, payment-gateway

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on boolean
>   in /app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Observer.php on line 46

can any one help about it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using official extension ? , try contacting them once

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe yes, i contacted them but they told me that there is not any error from their side and told me to check my magento code!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?